# Time clock using built in RTC of STM32 bluebill

Tags: stm32, iot, bluepill

I am new in STM32 development and trying to built RTC clock that display's time on oled display.
But on screen some  random unidentified symbols are displaying by the below code.

```
 while(1){
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
        HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
        uint8_t *a = sTime.Hours;
         char* buffer2;
          int i;

          buffer2 = malloc(9);
          if (!buffer2)
                 break;

          buffer2[8] = 0;
          for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            buffer2[7 - i] = (((*a) >> i) & (0x01)) + '0';

          puts(buffer2);

//      sprintf(date,"Date: %02d.%02d.%02d\t",sDate.Date,sDate.Month,sDate.Year);
//      sprintf(time,"Time: %02d.%02d.%02d\r\n",sTime.Hours,sTime.Minutes,sTime.Seconds);
               SSD1306_GotoXY (0,0);
                   SSD1306_Puts (buffer2, &Font_11x18, 1);
                   SSD1306_GotoXY (0, 30);
                   SSD1306_Puts ("CLOCK", &Font_11x18, 1);
                   SSD1306_UpdateScreen();
                   HAL_Delay (1000);


     }
```

Here is my clock configuration

[image]

Comment: This code is just really confusing. Is your compiler giving you any warnings that you are ignoring? e.g. `sTime.Hours` is a `uint8_t` and you are assigning it to a `uint8_t *`? There's no need to call malloc in this code, just declare a suitable array on the stack. I don't know what you're trying to achieve with your right shifts and bit masks.

Comment: Do you have a UART that you can log things on? If not, try to set that up first, then add copious logging to see what your code is doing and if it makes sense. Then try to show something on the display.

Comment: Are you sure the the display is showing garbage and not what you're telling it to show? Have you checked the values of all variables when drawing function is called? What kinds of characters are displayed? Please, give more info. It's always better to give too much info than too little

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I appreciate your help. I have resolved the issue. Basically SSD1306_Puts takes char string value but I was passing an uint8_t variable casted into buffer that's why junk values were displaying on OLED.